# If exists sql error combine 2 select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

When a subquery is not introduced with EXISTS, only one expression can be specified in the selection list.error. Not sure how to do the if exist statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
t1.id,t1.scn,t1.vsl_name,case when t1.id = t1.id  THEN 'IMPORT' ELSE '0' END AS import_export,
dbo.fn_format_datetime(t1.act_arr_dt_tm) AS act_arr_dt_tm,
dbo.fn_format_datetime(t1.act_dept_dt_tm) AS act_dept_dt_tm,
(       SELECT t1.scn, COUNT(t1.id) AS total_count_bl_status_c
        FROM ccosbl t1
        INNER JOIN vesvoy t2 ON t2.scn= t1.scn
        WHERE t1.status_ind= 'C'
        GROUP BY t1.scn)
FROM vesvoy t1
INNER JOIN ccosbl t2 ON t2.scn = t1.scn
WHERE t2.status_ind = 'C'
GROUP BY t1.scn,t1.vsl_name,t1.act_arr_dt_tm,t1.act_dept_dt_tm,t1.id
```

I need to combine both select statement as one. Is there any other ways to do that in sql?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? A count of everything doesn't require a subquery.

Comment: Hi @hunt what do you mean "combine both select statement" where's your first query and the second one?

Comment: @reds first is the select distinct and second is the select statement in brackets.

Comment: Any result that you've got so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using a correlated subquery then you need to make sure that only one column is included into the select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
t1.id,t1.scn,t1.vsl_name,case when t1.id = t1.id  THEN 'IMPORT' ELSE '0' END AS import_export,
dbo.fn_format_datetime(t1.act_arr_dt_tm) AS act_arr_dt_tm,
dbo.fn_format_datetime(t1.act_dept_dt_tm) AS act_dept_dt_tm,
(       SELECT COUNT(t4.id) AS total_count_bl_status_c
        FROM ccosbl t4
        INNER JOIN vesvoy t5 ON t4.scn= t5.scn
        WHERE t1.status_ind= 'C' and t4.scn = t2.scn)
FROM vesvoy t1
INNER JOIN ccosbl t2 ON t2.scn = t1.scn
WHERE t2.status_ind = 'C'
GROUP BY t1.scn,t1.vsl_name,t1.act_arr_dt_tm,t1.act_dept_dt_tm,t1.id
```

However, the better approach will be to use a subquery with the join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
t1.id,t1.scn,t1.vsl_name,case when t1.id = t1.id  THEN 'IMPORT' ELSE '0' END AS import_export,
dbo.fn_format_datetime(t1.act_arr_dt_tm) AS act_arr_dt_tm,
dbo.fn_format_datetime(t1.act_dept_dt_tm) AS act_dept_dt_tm,
t3.total_count_bl_status_c
FROM vesvoy t1
INNER JOIN ccosbl t2 ON t2.scn = t1.scn
LEFT JOIN
(       SELECT t4.scn, COUNT(t4.id) AS total_count_bl_status_c
        FROM ccosbl t4
        INNER JOIN vesvoy t5 ON t4.scn= t5.scn
        WHERE t4.status_ind= 'C'
        GROUP BY t4.scn) t3
ON t2.scn = t3.scn
WHERE t2.status_ind = 'C'
GROUP BY t1.scn,t1.vsl_name,t1.act_arr_dt_tm,t1.act_dept_dt_tm,t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t3.id t3.scn,total_count_bl_status_c,act_arr_dt_tm,act_dept_dt_tm,vsl_name,case when t3.id = t3.id  THEN 'IMPORT' ELSE '0' END AS import_export,
dbo.fn_format_datetime(t3.act_arr_dt_tm) AS act_arr_dt_tm,
dbo.fn_format_datetime(t3.act_dept_dt_tm) AS act_dept_dt_tm from
(SELECT t2.scn, COUNT(t2.id) AS total_count_bl_status_c
        FROM ccosbl t1
        INNER JOIN 
        vesvoy t2 
        ON t2.scn= t1.scn
        WHERE t1.status_ind= 'C'
        GROUP BY t1.scn)as t3
inner join 

(SELECT * from ccosbl) as t4 on 
ON t4.scn = t3.scn
```

Comment: It's just a guess i don't have your table data.. Much better if you show more sample data here and an expected result.